# covid19 analytics package not installing?

Tags: r

```
Warning: package ‘covid19.analytics’ was built under R version 4.2.2
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘covid19.analytics’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 namespace ‘cli’ 3.3.0 is already loaded, but >= 3.4.0 is required
```

Running Covid19 analytics, R is updated, Rstudio is up to date but no avail.

Comment: Which version of R and the cli package do you have installed?

Comment: `‘cli’ 3.3.0 is already loaded, but >= 3.4.0 is required` -- upgrade your `cli` package.